# Derivative of a integral with trig function in limit

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometric-integrals

Im trying to solve the following question:

The Derivative of the integral of (sin(t))/t dt with the upper limit of arcsin(x) and the lower limit of 1.

As far as I understand its easy to find the derivative of integral if the upper limit is larger than the lower limit and equal to x. But now I have a function as the upper limit. How can you solve that?

Comment: Hint: the chain rule.

Comment: Newton leibinitz rule...

Comment: if the upper limit would have been just x, then the answer would have been just sin(t)/t. But now I have a function as the upper limit? Isn't there a specifik rule for cases like this? In Swedish its called "Analysens huvudsats", something like "The fundamental theorem of analysis" or something like that. But I don't understand how you use it..

Comment: @PeterNiklas $x$ is a function... you just apply the chain rule like you do when it's $x$...

Comment: If it is easy, do you mind showing the calculations?

Comment: @PeterNiklas $${d\over dx}\int_a^{f(x)} g(x) dx = g(f(x))f'(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its most general form, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Analysis) states that for an appropriate integrand,

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)} ^{v(x)} f(t) \ dt = f(v(x))v'(x) - f(u(x))u'(x) $$

So for your integral,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_1 ^{\arcsin x} \frac{\sin t}{t} \ dt = \frac{\sin{(\arcsin x)}}{\arcsin x} \frac{d}{dx} (\arcsin x) $$

Can you finish?